# How do I set the path.repo in Docker compose 3?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I have the following Docker-compose 3 file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:6.2.4
    container_name: elasticsearch
    ...
    ...
    volumes:
      - /path/to/elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - /path/to/elasticsearch/backup:/opt/elasticsearch/backup
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - elasticnetwork
```

So, I've set my path.repo to /path/to/elasticsearch/backup. However, running curl http://127.0.0.1:9200/_nodes/?pretty results in no path.repo:

```
"settings" : {
        ...
        "path" : {
          "logs" : "/usr/share/elasticsearch/logs",
          "home" : "/usr/share/elasticsearch"
        },
        ...
      },
```

I'm expecting to see `"repo" : ["/opt/elasticsearch/backup"]` in the path.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation, You have to set your `path.repo` in your `elasticsearch.yml` file. This file is at `/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/` directory in your image.

So, your compose file should look something like this:

```
    version: '3'
    services:
      elasticsearch:
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:6.2.4
        container_name: elasticsearch
        volumes:
          - elastic-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
          - elastic-backup:/usr/share/elasticsearch/backup
          - ./elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        ports:
          - 9200:9200
        environment:
          discovery.type: single-node
    volumes:
      elastic-data:
      elastic-backup:
```

and your `elasticsearch.yml` should have these:

```
    cluster.name: "docker-cluster"
    network.host: 0.0.0.0
    
    # minimum_master_nodes need to be explicitly set when bound on a public IP
    # # set to 1 to allow single node clusters
    # # Details: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/17288
    # discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
    path.repo: ["/usr/share/elasticsearch/backup"]
```

After starting the container, I could see the `repo` in the `http://127.0.0.1:9200/_nodes/?pretty` response:

```
    "settings" : {
            "cluster" : {
              "name" : "docker-cluster"
            },
            "node" : {
              "name" : "3cUpSf-"
            },
            "path" : {
              "logs" : "/usr/share/elasticsearch/logs",
              "home" : "/usr/share/elasticsearch",
              "repo" : [
                "/usr/share/elasticsearch/backup"
              ]
            },
```

From comment:

> There is an user called elasticsearch which is created in this image and Elasticsearch binary runs in context of this user not root user, so this user doesn't have write permission on `/opt` directory inside the container, but it does have enough permission on `/usr/share/elastisearch` directory. That's the reason in my above example I have used this directory instead of the `/opt/` dir.

Comment: I'm now trying to create a snapshot but get an "access_denied_exception" error: "failed to create blob container".

Comment: I am also having the issue of `access_denied_exception` even through my `path.repo` is under `/usr/share/elastisearch`

Comment: @SohailAhmed I solved it this way. DO NOT use this in PROD. I passed the path.repo as an env variable. Then I created the repo directory(with FULL permission) manually in docker's volumn directory. You can create/link me a question where I can paste a full answer if you still have the problem.

Comment: @LuyangDu Thank you very much. I passed path.repo in docker-compose as `environment` and made uid 1000 the owner of repo directory. It worked because in container uid 1000 is for elasticsearch user, even though on host uid 1000 is for ubuntu user.

Comment: This gives access denied errors with 7.xx versions of ES

Comment: @IshanJain I believe [this documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/docker.html#_configuration_files_must_be_readable_by_the_elasticsearch_user) will help you to resolve the access denied issue.

Comment: An alternative for permissions errors might be correcting them after mounting the Docker volume: `docker exec --user root -it elasticsearch chown elasticsearch:root /usr/share/elasticsearch/backup`.

Answer (score 16):

```
version: "3"
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:6.8.2
    environment:
      - 'path.repo=/opt/elasticsearch/backup'
```

Comment: The quotes are indeed not necessary, but in order for this answer to be super-complete, it's worth mentioning that restarting the elasticsearch service is not enough, because the environment is only applied during `up` command.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my working Docker Compose. I am using an external path which is mounted under volumes.

I am using a custom network which can be created with `docker network create --driver bridge apps`

```
version: '3.7'
x-common-config: &common-config
  networks:
    - network
  restart: always
  ulimits:
    nproc: 65535
    nofile:
      soft: 65535
      hard: 65535
    memlock:
      soft: -1
      hard: -1

services:
  elasticsearch:
    <<: *common-config
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.1
    container_name: elasticsearch
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    environment:
      - node.name=elasticsearch
      - cluster.name=elasticsearch-cluster
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms2g -Xmx2g"
      - "path.repo=/usr/share/backup"    
    volumes:
      - data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - /mnt/elastic-backup:/usr/share/backup
  kibana:
    <<: *common-config
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.6.1
    container_name: kibana
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: kibana
      XPACK.SECURITY.ENCRYPTIONKEY: <KEY>
    depends_on:
    - elasticsearch

volumes:
  data:
    driver: local

networks:
  network:
    driver: bridge
    external:
      name: apps
```